# Anything that is typed into a browser's address bar is a GET request?

Tags: http

When I type a url into a brower's address bar is it is *always* a GET request (meaning, it's definitely not a POST request) right?

Comment: It is for a URL. If it isn't a URL, then the browser might decide to invoke a search, which might trigger a POST request. Or if you're going to get picky, some malware may be intercepting you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.

---